# WhatsApp VoIP Push non-delivery and iOS 11

Tags: ios, push-notification, whatsapp

There's lots of problems with push in general in iOS 11.0n. I have two apps, one uses silent pushes and I can reproduce problems with the pushes not being delivered. Theres nothing I can do to fix it, its an Apple issue, they have changed the behavior of silent pushes and also introduced a bug with iOS 11.0.

However I also have another app which uses VoIP push. WhatsApp uses VoIP push and their users have been experiencing lots of notification issues with iOS 11.0n too:
https://whatsappen.com/news/5465/many-complaints-whatsapp-notifications-ios-11-update-solution

That link above (and WhatsApp web site states something sililar)

> It’s indeed an iOS 11 bug. It is affecting users who habitually force
>   close their app.

I'm unable to reproduce any similar issue with my app which uses VoIP push (tried force quitting it several times).
And that's my problem - the fact that I can't reproduce it. Just because I can't reproduce it doesn't mean it doesn't affect my app.

If there is a problem with VoIP push and therefore potentially with my app's behavior I would like to reproduce it, and fix it.
WhatsApp claim they fixed their issue without waiting for a new release from Apple, so it must be something they can work around.

I would like to know if anybody knows what this VoIP push problem is with WhatsApp and what they did to fix it.